# Is it possible to connect two 4k monitors to one thunderbolt port?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

I want to buy the new macbook pro 13" without touchbar and be able to connect two 4k monitors AND the charger. But this macbook only has 2 ports.

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do is possible, but not without either using an adapter, dock, or the right kind of displays. For example:

- you can use a display that allows you to daisy-chain to another display (i.e. you have a charger plugged into one of your ports, and you have one display connected to the other port and a second display connected to the first display)
- you purchase a dock such as the OWC's [Thunderbolt 3 Dock](https://eshop.macsales.com/preorder/owc-thunderbolt-3-dock/).
- you purchase at least one display that will provide charging power to your MBP (e.g. the [LG UltraFine 4K Display](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207447)).

You may want to also read:

- [About Thunderbolt ports and displays](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204154)
- [Connect with Thunderbolt 3 on your new MacBook Pro](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207256)
- [Use the LG UltraFine 4K Display with your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207447)

**NOTE:** IMHO, if you're wanting to run two 4K displays you probably should invest in a MBP with four Thunderbolt ports, as this is likely to provide more flexibility in terms of usage and the variety of devices you can purchase to meet your needs.

Comment: You're right. For the price of these docks and the ultraFine, I'd rather invest in the touchbar model and be better prepared for the usb-c era. But just curious, do to know of any monitor that you can daisy-chain on a Mac? From my research I found that the apple's old thunderbolt display was the only one that supported that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cheap solution - for the 2nd display, use a mini-displayport to USB-C adapter that also has power-input. Something like this - [https://www.amazon.com/Paheven-Display-JellyFish-Mini-DisplayPort-Charging/dp/B079CBNK8M/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B079CBNK8M)